# Oracle Request Select all tables for schemas with number of row

Tags: sql, oracle

I would to get all tables for many schemas, with for each tables the number of rows it contains. I would like something like this :

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COUNT(TABLE_NAME)
FROM DBA_USERS
WHERE OWNER IN ('TOTO', 'TITI');
```

I have to do the request with "/ as sysdba", that's why I try to use dba_users table.
Do you have an idea why I can do this ?

Thanks for your help,

Steve

Comment: That question is to get all the tables of _a_ schema; this one is to get all tables for _many_ scemas.  I don't know Oracle so I can't tell if the answers to that question apply easily to this question.

Comment: @WayneConrad - they do, with a little tweaking; in Rob's answer just use `dba_tables` instead of `user_tables`, and add the `owner` to the table name in the count.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS
FROM DBA_TABLES
WHERE OWNER IN ('TOTO', 'TITI');
```

It is not required to by SYS user, all you need is the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege.

**Note**: Column NUM_ROWS does not necessarily show the exact number of rows, it's just the number based from collected statistics. In order to get the exact number for each table you would have to write dynamic SQL statements.

**UPDATE:**

For exact count you can create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION COUNT_ROWS(TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
   res NUMBER;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||TABLE_NAME INTO res;
   RETURN res;
END COUNT_ROWS;
/

SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS, Count_rows(OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME) as num_rows_exact
FROM DBA_TABLES
WHERE OWNER IN ('TOTO', 'TITI');
```

Be aware, if your schema contains many tables with many data, this query may take some time to execute.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I don't want to do, to use num_rows. Do you know how to do it dynamically ?